# How do I stop my character from moving forward if an object he's holding cannot move?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a Rigidbody 3D character I'm moving in the world using x and z velocity.  He can maneuver around the ground but not through kinematic obstacles.  When he picks up a long pipe to carry around, how can I stop him from moving around if the pipe is 'stuck' on some obstacle in the world?  Right now I'm trying to parent the pipe to him when he picks it up, but then the pipe just ignores collision with obstacles.

Comment: when you parent the object do you disable it's Rigidbody component?

Comment: I think there are two way - you either stick with parenting and disable or maybe even have to destroy the Rigidbody component, in that case your players Rigibody should (hopefully) start treat the other objects colliders as part of the player Rigidbody; or alternatively you could skip the parenting and rather look into [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html) and for instance use a [FixedJoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) (might have to enable `Enable Collision`)

Answer (score 0):

I thought of an idea. You can implement canMove function that takes direction parameter. Basically when you are about to move your character controller, check the object in player's hand with CanMove function. Give it a direction and move the player if it is possible.

You can implement this kind of thing to any objects if you use interfaces. Like this.

interface:

```
public interface ICarriable
{
    public bool CanMove(Vector3 direction);
}
```

Character controller:

```
public class Player : MonoBehavior
{
     private void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if(carriableObject.CanMove(direction)
         {
             Move(direction);
         }
     }
}
```

Object:

```
public class Bigpipes : MonoBehavior, ICarriable
{
      public bool CanMove(Vector3 direction)
      {
          if(Physics.BoxCast(transform.position, direction, objectSize, out RaycastHit hit, maxDistance, obstacleLayers))
          {
              if(hit.distance < 0.2f)
              {
                 return false;
              }
          }
          return true;
      }
}
```

Something like this would be much cleaner than changing the parent. Also changing parent with two rigidbodys might cause weird problems in the future.

Note: I haven't tested the syntax of the code. So you might need to rearrange the parameters as you see fit. But I hope you get the gist.